# ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 1 dimensions

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

The `tf.reduce_mean()` function sums the elements of an array in such a way that the index referred to in the *axis* argument.

In the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([1, 2, 3])
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

So for the line

```
print(sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(x)))
```

The output is: 6

In order to generate the same output, I need to sum all the elements in a way to reduce the number of columns. So I need to set *axis* = 1 right?

```
print(sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(x, 1)))
```

But I get an error:

> ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 1 dimensions

But if I set axis = 0, I get 6. Why is this?

Answer (score 6):

The error you get is `ValueError: Invalid reduction dimension 1 for input with 1 dimensions`. This pretty much means that if you can't reduce the dimension of a 1-dimensional tensor.

For an N x M tensor, setting axis = 0 will return an 1xM tensor, and setting axis = 1 will return a Nx1 tensor. Consider the following example from the tensorflow documentation:

```
# 'x' is [[1, 1, 1]
#         [1, 1, 1]]
tf.reduce_sum(x) ==> 6
tf.reduce_sum(x, 0) ==> [2, 2, 2]
tf.reduce_sum(x, 1) ==> [3, 3]
```

Comment: because it is a row vector? but when I change the axis argument to 0 (row)  I get 6. Why is this?

Comment: as lordingtar explains above, while setting axis=1, you say TF to reduce along 1-D, which obviously raises an error. It looks to me that your misunderstanding what is 'row' on the one hand, and what is 'column' on the other one.

Answer (score 2):

"Note that one way to choose the last axis in a tensor is to use negative indexing (axis=-1)"

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you elaborate, linking this answer more to the user's question?  It seems that in the question their tensor was a 1D array.  Your answer would help if it was a 2D or greater array.